# Is there a way via echo shell_exec to show in out ethernet connections from the server?

Tags: php, network-traffic

In my linux server, when I type "iftop" into my terminal, it enters a mini program that show network traffic...

I'm looking for a way to echo the last 10 or 20 connections in / out via a shell_exec...

```
echo '<hr>IFTOP -> <pre>'.shell_exec("iftop").'</pre><br>';
```

But it says sh: `iftop: command not found`...

I tried ntop.org, but it's not what I'm looking for, and I have to open port 3000...

is it possible to show last server connections via echo shell_exec ?
Any iftop alternative is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete path to call the `iftop` command. You don't have the complete environment in you shell command.

Comment: I found the path and modified to shell_exec("/usr/sbin/iftop 2>&1") but it shows an error talking about permission. is there an other command to acheive this ?